# Looking for a purely disk based key-value cache for a large dataset in Java

Tags: java, caching, disk

I currently have a postgres database with a simple schema of a fixed length key (20 bytes) and a fixed length value (40 bytes). Its a massive table with billions of rows, but unfortunately we have lots of duplicated data. We'd like to separate this table into its own data store.

Ideally, I'm looking for ways to store this data on a large hard drive where it can be queried on occasion. Performance is not critical for reads, disk access is fast enough - no need to store anything in memory. And there is rarely new data added after the initial load.

If there is no product available I would be willing to roll my own with suggestions. I originally thought of using the key as a folder path based on the byte /0/32/231/32/value but obviously that results in too many files/folders on a single disk. Is there an optimization that can be used since both keys and values are fixed length?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try some pure Java database engines like [MapDb](http://www.mapdb.org/) or [LevelDB](https://github.com/dain/leveldb).